# Finding usages of Java Reflection in a codebase

Tags: java, reflection, refactoring

I'd like to avoid using Reflection where possible. I have a legacy codebase to refactor that has at least one getMethod(), and now I'm afraid to delete functions that seem to be dead.

How can I easily find places in the code where I can work backwards from? Is there a static analyser that can collect Reflection API usage?

Searching for every variant of getClass() and getMethod() seems tedious.

Comment: What about grepping for `getClass(` and `getMethod(`? Sometimes (quite often actually) the simplest tools are the best.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any tools on top of my head but it wouldn't be to hard to write script which traverses project structure, going through all directories(packages) and checks in each file if it contains import of `java.lang.reflect` or calls to `getMethod()`/ `getClass()`.

There is **FileVisitor** interface in java which can help you do this.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810272/iterate-through-a-filesystem-without-using-binary-tree-or-recursion/30811175#30811175) answer might also help you as an alternative to [FileVisitor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html)
. There is implementation of breadth first search traversal of directories, so you would have to add on top of it:

1. Read all files from directory
2. For each file check if it contains reflection keywords as mentioned above
3. Generate report for each file found

Keep in mind that reflection might be there for problems which are otherwise not possible to solve. Think of frameworks which must work with any supplied classes, processing of runtime annotations and so on.
Hence i would suggest you to be sure that the problem solved by reflection can be and is worth refactoring.